# does var onload mean that it should run when page is loaded

Tags: javascript

// test.js //

```
    var testObj = {};
    testObj.init = function(){
        console.log('google');
    }

var onload = testObj.init;
```

/// what does it mean, does it mean it gets executed when script loaded or what, I just can't understand it as it is not looging into console anything under Google Chrome plugin...

Comment: sorry for a dumb q, but really can't get my head around

Comment: Are you trying to execute a function on page load and need help, or did you find this code and are trying to figure out what it is trying to accomplish?

Comment: well the second indeed trying to get myself around the JSJAC lib. =)

Comment: just use 

var onload = testObj.init();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it like giving your dog 2 names:

```
var spot = new Dog();
var comeHereSpot = function ()  { return spot; }    
var comeHereBoy = comeHereSpot;
```

Whether you call `comeHereSpot` or `comeHereBoy` the same dog will come running.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that your variable onload now points to

```
function(){
    console.log('google');
}
```

onload is just the name of a local variable here.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `onload` is simply the name of a local variable. The `var` keyword declares local variables. You're setting the value of `onload` to `testObj.init`, which is a function that prints 'google' to the console.

To make it run the function on page load, set `window.onload` to the value of the function.

```
window.onload = testObj.init;
```

Or, better yet, use [event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Adding_Event_Handlers) to attach an "onload" event to the `window` object. (To make this easier, use a JavaScript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), but I recommend you first learn how it all works.)

Answer (score 0):

It means that variable onload is a reference to the function testObj.init. `onload()` will execute the function and output 'google' to the console.

Answer (score 0):

No, it only means that you assign it to a variable named `onload`.

Depending on the scope of the code it might actually work, if the variable name collides with the `onload` property of the `window` object. In that case a variable would not be created, but it would use the existing property instead. You should not rely on this behaviour though, you should always specify it as a property of the object:

```
window.onload = testObj.init;
```

Comment: thanks, it is just a oxjs library that I am stuck with, there is not really much of a documentation , and example is just not working....=(

Comment: That would only work without the `var` keyword. `var` declares a local variable. If the code was simply `onload = testObj.init` then it may work.

Comment: indeed it is with a var, here is a code part "
var onload = DemoApp.JSJaC.init; "
I just was confused, anyhow thanks a lot to ya'll

Comment: @musicfreak: It may be tempting to use `onload = fn;` but should be [avoided](http://perfectionkills.com/onloadfunction-considered-harmful/)...

Comment: @CMS: I know, I wasn't saying that you should, I was just disproving @Guffa's statement.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing is logged because you are simply setting `onload` to be a pointer to the function `testObj.init` which only gets the function's code.  To actually *run* it, you must call `testObj.init()`.

More about onload…

`onload` is a property of an HTML element that can be set to run javascript.  For example:

```
<html>…
… <body onload="testObj.init()"> …
…</html>
```

This means that when the "body" element is loaded, the function `testObj.init()` is run.

The "onload" property can also be attatched by javascript, as in:

```
window.onload=myFunction();
```

Comment: yep — "onload" is a standalone variable in your example.

Comment: Everything you said is true, but you didn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out musicfreak, lost my train of thought for a moment there… hehe